# Do I have to repeat the confirmation to a protocol in the subclass?

Tags: iphone, protocols

Hey,
I have got a parent class, which is conform to the NSCoding protocol.

So do I have to repeat the confirmation in my child class again, or is it automatically conform to it because of the descent?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave it off, but only the parent's implementation will take hold (unless you override it in your subclass).

```
@protocol Awesomeable
-(void)foo;
@end

@interface Base : NSObject <Awesomeable>
@end

@interface Child : Base
@end


Child *child = [[Child alloc] init];
[child foo]; //valid call
```